# Spring Boot : Disable Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, weblogic12c

We are using **Quartz Scheduler** in our Spring Boot Application.
There is a scenario for which we want to disable it.

We have tried using `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = Constant.QUARTZ_ENABLED)` option on our class.
We have defined `quartz.enabled = false` property in `application.properties` file.

However when we run on Tomcat server locally on Spring Tool Suite it is working as expected (meaning it is not invoking the quartz scheduler).

**But when same code is deployed on Weblogic, the scheduler is still running.**

Should we try putting `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = Constant.QUARTZ_ENABLED)` annotation at method level. specifically the method where trigger is used?

We have gone through the options mentioned on various forums but still not reached the solution.

Is there any way we can

**1. Stop the scheduler from starting
Or
2. Stop the Job from getting triggered**

Thanks in advance.